# How to swap two pairs in a singly linked list using the links?

Tags: java, linked-list, swap

Iam working on a small home task to swap two adjacent elements in a linked list using only links, not the data. I tried the following code but i couldn't swap the elements. Can someone please correct my switchPairs method?(There might be some errors in other methods as well, but i'll fix them).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Link{

    int data;
    Link next;

    Link(int dat){
        data=dat;
        next=null;
    }

    void display(){
        System.out.print(data +"\n");
    }

}

class LinkedList{

    Link first;
    Link current;
    Link last;
    Link temp;
    int counter;
    Link front,prev;

    LinkedList(){

        first=null;
        counter=0;
    }

    void insert(int val){
        Link newLink=new Link(val);
        if(first==null){
            first=newLink;
            last=newLink;
        } else {   
            last.next=newLink;
            last=newLink;
        }
    }

    void display() {
        System.out.print("You gave the list: \n");
        current =first;
        while(current!=null) {
            System.out.print(current.data +"\n");
            current=current.next;
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    public void switchPairs() {
        prev=front;
        if(front!=null && front.next != null) {
            Link temp = front;
            front = front.next;
            temp.next = front.next;
            front.next = temp;
            prev = temp;
        }
        while(prev !=null && prev.next != null && prev.next.next != null) {
            Link first_node =prev.next;
            Link second_node = first_node.next;
            first_node.next = second_node.next;
            second_node.next = first_node;
            prev.next = second_node;
            prev = first_node;
        }
    }
}

public class Task {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a,b,c,d,e,f;
        LinkedList newNode=new LinkedList();
        System.out.print("Enter 6 numbers for the list\n");
        Scanner key=new Scanner(System.in);
        a=key.nextInt();
        b=key.nextInt();
        c=key.nextInt();
        d=key.nextInt();
        e=key.nextInt();
        f=key.nextInt();
        newNode.insert(a);
        newNode.insert(b);
        newNode.insert(c);
        newNode.insert(d);
        newNode.insert(e);
        newNode.insert(f);
        newNode.switchPairs();
        newNode.display();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is very difficult to read and your question needs to be more clear.  What exactly do you expect and what exactly is happening (expected output vs actual output)?

Comment: I am unable to swap two adjacent elements in the list. and switchPair method is used for swapping.

Comment: It is not swapping at all.

Comment: Can you give an example of actual input and expected output? it isn't clear what `switchPairs` is supposed to achieve. It doesn't take any arguments so it's not going to swap two specific items.